# How to merge 2 huge tables with only geometry in common without duplicates

Tags: postgresql, sql

I've got 2 tables with several millions of rows. Because of poor data management, they don't have any ids at all or anything that helps match them up except for the geom

I've tried doing

```
insert into table1(random_columns, geom )
select random_columns, geom  from table2 a where not exists (select b.geom from table1 c where b.geom = a.geom  )
```

Problem with this query was that it did not complete for 3 days!!!! So I had to cancel.

Both geom columns are indexed

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the PostGIS function `st_equals` instead of the `=` operator, the query planner will be able to use the geometry index and work more efficiently.

You can check if that's actually happening by checking the query plan using the `EXPLAIN` command before your query.

Comment: Doesn't make much sense but giving it a try. It does seem to use the index now. I thought about converting geom to text and indexing that actually

Comment: @Luffydude Operators and their capabilities (e.g. index awareness) are defined along with the data type it is used for, and thus the `=` operator is not the same for type `GEOMETRY` as it is for e.g. numeric types! Needless to say, the index itself is completely different, thus a simple `=` wouldn't make much sense except for *bitwise* equality!

Comment: holy  I started the query and went to the toilet and to get myself a tea. When I came back not only did it finish but it did 1.1m inserts in just 1m34s!! Something that was taking more than 3 days beforehand @ThingumaBob thanks for the explanation

Comment: you could always pre-process using ST_Intersects to give values to features that overlap, then only take the ones you want...?

Comment: @Luffydude oh, also, next time just test for bolean existence with `... WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM...`; no need to fetch any values.